# same number of observations but not significant?

Tags: correlation

If we two time series `(x,y)`with the same number of observations.
We then computed the Pearson correlation with `z`, which has the same number of observations as `x` and `y` (`corr` between `x and z` ,`corr` between `y and z`)

```
   Is it possible to encounter this case:
    - there is a significant (p<0.05)correlation between x and z
     - there is NO significant (p<0.05)correlation between y and z
```

even if they the have same number of observations!

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible, what is the reason for the surprise? Take x=z and random y, for example. The equal number of observations doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

Yes, of course it is possible, what is the reason for the surprise? Take $x=z$ and random $y$, for example.  The equal number of observations doesn't mean much. – psarka